# Verify existence of an item in a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I check for the existence of an item in a dropdownlist in vb.net?

Here's my not working code:

```
    dim ddlTestDropdown as dropdownlist    

    ddlTestDropdown = New DropDownList()

    If(ddlTestDropdown.Items.FindByValue("42") Is Not nothing)
        Console.WriteLine("It's there")
    End If
```

it won't let me compare the returned `ListItem` to nothing

Comment: You are creating new DropDownlist and not assigning any items, before trying to read items from that list.

Comment: If this isnt *just* a series of clerical errors, then you haven't provided a complete code example. This code has a number of issues.

Comment: Creating an example where the result is not there is my intent. I need the code to work correctly when the item is not there, as is it will not even compile. My question is how do I write it correctly so that it will compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The error is from saying `Is Not` the fix is to say:

```
If(Not ddlTestDropdown.Items.FindByValue("42") Is Nothing)
```

Alternate answer:
Here's what I found to do this. Like @praythyus tried you need to test for contains, but vb.net only lets you do contains on a listitem. So I combined what I did with what he did and this worked:

```
 Dim SetThisIfExists = ddlTestDropdown.Items.FindByValue("42")
 If(ddlTestDropdown.Items.Contains(SetThisIfExists))
     ddlTestDropdown.SelectedIndex = ddlTestDropdown.Items.IndexOf(SetThisIfExists)
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for giving C# syntax. Can you try with

as @RS said, you need to fill the ddl after initializing.

```
if(ddlTestDropdown.Items.Contains("42"))
{
}
```

Or instead of `FindByValue` can you use `FindByText`

Comment: You really need to answer this question in VB in order to provide a valid answer... or just a meaningful explanation of what is incorrect about the OP.

Comment: It's simple in C# and works as expected, but this doesn't translate to vb.net, and that's my issue exactly